# md-chips with floating label in Material AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I need to have a md-chips on a form with a floating label.

So a try with the autocomplete inside the md-chips and with md-floating-label, the problem is that the floating label is alway moving foward.

```
<md-chips >
   <md-autocomplete md-floating-label="Search for a vegetable">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </md-autocomplete>
    <md-chip-template>
        <span>{{$chip.name}}</span>
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

[You can check here how it is working now](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvoGBa).

Anyone knows a way to have the label fixed on the beggining of the md-chips? Or a directive that does the work for me.

[Here a example with the expected result](https://teamwertarbyte.github.io/material-ui-chip-input/?selectedKind=ChipInput&selectedStory=with%20floating%20label&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to tap into `<md-autocomplete>`s logic for keeping the floating label up when `ctrl.selectedVegetables.length` is truthy (I'm assuming a custom directive that would require md-autocomplete's controller and inject the logic into it could do that, until this method is developed by angular-material team themselves), but here's how you can place the floating label before the chips, which results in a more decent UX:

```css
md-chips-wrap.md-chips {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
md-chips-wrap > .md-chip-input-container {
  order: -1;
}
```

Updated bin: [bLNzKg](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/bLNzKg)

Comment: I don't know if it's from my browser but the bin o set in your answer works the same as the one in the question.(I'm using chrome)

Comment: @FxmL, you're right, I forgot to save it after i changed `md-chips-wrap` into `md-chips-wrap.md-chips`. However, the code posted here was correct. And I explained you what I was doing, in principle.